# vagrant up hangs but vagrant ssh works

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm working on `os x 10.9.4`, and the `vagrant --version` shows 1.3.3.

After waking up os x from sleep mode(in a different network environment), vagrant up hangs at `Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...` then: `Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot.`

I tried to

`config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
 end`

and the vm boots normally and I can login using username/password vagrant

Also, at this point, in another terminal, if I try`vagrant ssh`, it will show `vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:` (I've never seen it asking password before) and I can login. The network of the vm seems to be fine and I can ping google.com within the vm.

Also, if I manually launch the vm directly from virtual box, I can also login via `vagrant ssh`(showing `vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:` again). The network is fine as well.

I've followed https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/wiki/%60vagrant-up%60-hangs-at-%22Waiting-for-VM-to-boot.-This-can-take-a-few-minutes%22    no luck, though. And I've also checked the ssh key. On the host, the insecure_private_key is `-rw-------`; and on vm, the authorized_keys shows `-rw-r--r--`

So, to sum up:

- `vagrant ssh` works (asking for password)
- I can ping within the vm
- **BUT `vagrant up` hangs**

I'm totally lost. Why the vm works but vagrant up hangs?

Comment: It can be really long guessing game trying to figure out what's gone wrong.

I suggest you to run 'vagrant up --debug' instead and try to see if you can recognize what's going on from the debug output. Maybe sharing it with us if it still not clear what's going on.

Also, I thing you should upgrade your Vagrant if you can. Yours is almost 1 year old, which in case of Vagrant might contain a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: Same here with vagrant 1.7.2 on ubuntu 14.04LTS... `vagrant up` hanging while trying to connect, `vagrant ssh` from another terminal works 'at once'. Two weaks ago, no problems with a particular box. What could have happened on the vagrant host, resulting to that behaviour? Although I've changed some ssh_config settings, I would exclude those changes, because `vagrant ssh` and ssh -p 2222 vagrant@localhost (NAT) does work.

Answer (score 0):

As trivial it sounds, but for me un- and reinstalling was the only option left.
Debugging didn't bring up any errors... it seemed `vagrant up` was just dying.